# Night Light option disabled in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I am having some issues with recent feature Night Light settings in Windows 10.

I am not able to turn it ON or OFF.

Windows 10 version - 1703
OS Build - 15063.13

Comment: I suggest heading over to SuperUser to ask this type of question. It has nothing to do with programming and is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Thanks, I will

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Go to time and date settings.
Change timezone where is daylight in world. (i had 10PM in IST so i set my timezone for PST where time is around 11AM)
Night shift will be disabled automatically.
Turn it ON and OFF.
Just do not Turn is ON ever !!!

Problem i had -
I ShutDown Laptop while Night Light was ON yesterday and when i Turned my Laptop ON, NightLight ON/OFF option is faded(Cant on/off, not Clickable)
Please try about solution and let me know if it helps . Peace guys !!
My Version - 1703 #15063.13

Comment: Seriously - not the place to post this. The question is off-topic.

Comment: Thanks, it worked :) Cheers!

Comment: @DavidMakogon - Yes this is the place to ask problems and give solution. if you dont know the answer then i helped. just this simple.

Comment: No, this is *not* the place to ask generic computer issues. That's what SuperUser is for. Not StackOverflow.

Comment: I have already tried their, let me know if you found answer there, that will be great